# how to add a custom theme in jquery mobile from theme roller site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themes, themeroller

I am trying to add a custom theme in my jquery mobile site.

I visited the theme roller site , i designed a theme and then i downloaded a zip file.

Inside there is a *themes folder* and an *index.html* . Inside the themes folder there is an *images folder* and *2 CSS files* :

**1)** `customTheme.css`

**2)** `customTheme.min.css`

I copy-pasted the 2) in my project folder.

Then in my project i do :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CEID</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
</head>
```

It should work right? What am i doing wrong here?

The theme doesnt work..

What i am designing looks like this :

[image]

What i get looks like this :

[image]

My html looks like this :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CEID</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/CustomTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The custom CSS i **was** using :

```
/* Home page banner */
h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(images/banner.png) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:220px;
    height:250px;
    margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Home page banner landscape */
.landscape h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner-landscape.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:480px;
    height:290px;
    margin:-10px auto -175px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.ui-listview .ui-li-icon {
     max-height: 32px !important;
      max-width: 32px !important; 
}

/* Home page icons */
.ui-li-icon {
    top:0.4em !important;
}
/* Make room for icons */
.ui-li-has-icon .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-icon {
    padding-left:47px;
}
```

The body of my html:

```
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <h2 id="banner">CEID Mobile</h2>

        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="information.html"><img src="images/info.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Πληροφορίες</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff.html"><img src="images/staff.png" alt="Staff" class="ui-li-icon">Προσωπικό</a></li>
                <li><a href="research.html"><img src="images/research.png" alt="Research" class="ui-li-icon">Έρευνα</a></li>
                <li><a href="undergraduates.html"><img src="images/undergraduates.png" alt="undergraduates" class="ui-li-icon">Προπτυχιακά</a></li>
                <li><a href="metaptyxiaka.html"><img src="images/graduates.png" alt="Graduates" class="ui-li-icon">Μεταπτυχιακά</a></li>
                <li><a href="students.html"><img src="images/students.png" alt="Students" class="ui-li-icon">Φοιτητές</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html"><img src="images/news.png" alt="News" class="ui-li-icon">Ανακοινώσεις</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </div>

        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="http://www.ceid.upatras.gr"><img src="images/info.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Μεταφορά στον Ιστότοπο</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: it doesnt work. the theme doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example won't work, take a look what you have :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="customTheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

There are 3 different css files. First one is your custom theme, second one is only structure css file (everything else), and last one is complete jQuery Mobile css file. Currently your last css file (complete one) is overriding custom css theme.

To solve your problem change everything to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="customTheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

Or even better remove **`jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css`** and use only:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="customTheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

What you need to understand, jQuery Mobile have 3 available css files. **`jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css`** should be used alone because it hase css for themes and structure. If you have custom themes then you only need to use custom theme css file and **`jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css`**.

**EDIT :**

Don't forget that you also need to add **`data-theme`** to your page DIV container:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
```

or you can add it only to your header, content and footer DIV's but I would advise you to add it to page DIV.

Comment: When i do as you say and only keep the custom theme and the structure , it works partly. The header takes the color that i assign to. However all the rest of the page looks terrible. There are no outlines around the buttons or the lists. Everything is white. The background has no color.. Any idea what i did wrong now?

Comment: Can you mail me your custom css and I will take a look? Also at least one page.

Comment: And tell me do the rest of your pages use a classic themes and only your header use a custom one?

Comment: Show me also your page BODY html.

Comment: i added it. But what do u need the body for? Do i need to add the theme in the body too?! I thought i would be enough to import it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31247/discussion-between-jonh-smid-and-gajotres)